# Not able to add new instance of model, not even using Django Admin panel

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-admin

For several months I am programing a web app using Django for learning purposes.

I created class me function based view to create new entries of many model but for this one something is off.

First I was unable to add using CBV, then I switch to function base view. I tried using forms.py or directly with template but every time I get clean console, good redirect but no new entry.

Then I tried to create it just using Admin panel but i would get something like "The performance review “PerformanceReview object (1e549e2c-4b3d-4030-9007-b889265ed908)” was added successfully.", but the list of objects was still empty.

As this message is basically a link when I try to follow it I get this message:

> Performance review with ID “1e549e2c-4b3d-4030-9007-b889265ed908” doesn’t exist. Perhaps it was deleted?

- I did 'makemigrations' and 'migrate'
- While this was happening rest of the app still worked as expected
- Admin.py has model registered
- All fields are correctly presented within Admin form
- Validators work correctly

```
from django.contrib import admin
from . models import PerformanceReview
# Register your models here.

admin.site.register(PerformanceReview)
```

I don't think that the rest of code is relevant as the Admin panel not working is the thing that puzzles me. This is my model:

```
class PerformanceReview(models.Model):
    job_instance = models.ForeignKey(JobInstance, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    performance_review_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    year = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(2022), MaxValueValidator(2060)], blank=False, null=False)

    hr_created = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    employee_submitted = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    manager_submitted = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    hr_submitted = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    done_employee = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=True)

    # Rate the overall quality of your work on a scale of 1 to 5, and provide specific examples that demonstrate your highest quality work.
    quality_rating_grade = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(5)], blank=True, null=True)
    quality_rating = models.TextField(max_length=2000, null=True, blank=True)

    # How consistently do you meet project deadlines? Rate your on-time delivery performance on a scale of 1 to 5, and provide examples of projects where you excelled in meeting deadlines.
    on_time_delivery_rating_grade = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(5)], blank=True, null=True)
    on_time_delivery_rating = models.TextField(max_length=2000, null=True, blank=True)

    # On a scale of 1 to 5, how effectively do you manage your workload and prioritize tasks? Provide examples of how you have efficiently managed your time and resources.
    workload_management_rating_grade = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(5)], blank=True, null=True)
    workload_management_rating = models.TextField(max_length=2000, null=True, blank=True)

    # Rate your attention to detail and accuracy in your work on a scale of 1 to 5, and provide specific examples of projects where your attention to detail made a significant impact.
    attention_to_detail_rating_grade = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(5)], blank=True, null=True)
    attention_to_detail_rating = models.TextField(max_length=2000, null=True, blank=True)
```

- Tried making small changes to model and migrating it
- Tried to work with forms.py
- Tried working only with html templates
- Tried function and CBV
- Tried using several users
- Tried using Admin panel

Comment: I tried your code, and it works fine so the issue is not in the models.py nor the admin.py.  It *might* be an issue with your **settings.py**.

Comment: To be honest I don't think that this is the case as I have other models, views and functionalities in general within same app. Same settings are applied for them and rest of the code works well.
Not much was changed from default version of settings.py (I cannot put code due to characters limitation for comment session.

Comment: Yes, I see.  Perhaps it isn't an issue with your settings.py.  At the same time, there is something within your code *that is not shown in your question*, which is causing the problem.  Maybe there is something in your code which is deleting the instance right after it is created?  Sorry, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Since this is test project, why don't you try to create a new database by:
1. Deleting all the files ( excluding the `init` file) inside `migrations` folder. 
2. Deleting the `sqlite.db` file.
3. Run `makemigrations` and `migrate` commands.

Then see if the problem persists.